# How to have shell expansion in Groovy?

Tags: bash, shell, groovy

Running this command in bash:

```
echo *
```

Gives this output:

> echo.groovy file1 file2

Running same command via groovy:

```
print 'echo *'.execute().text
```

Gives:

> *

I realize this is because `*` expansion is done by the shell. So I try this:

```
print '/bin/bash -c "echo *"'.execute().text
```

This gives nothing at all.

**How can I execute shell commands in Groovy while taking benefit of shell expansion?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a list instead of a string to ensure that the arguments are passed correctly and not misinterpreted:

```
println(['/bin/bash', '-c', 'echo *'].execute().text)
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the answer given by `Raniz`, your existing multi-line shell scripts with all the benefits of shell expansion can be executed as follows:

```
def command='''echo *
START=1
END=10
for ((i=START; i<=END; i++))
do
   echo "i: $i"
done
'''

print (['/bin/bash', '-c', command].execute().text)
```

Output:

```
echo.groovy file1 file2
i: 1
i: 2
i: 3
i: 4
i: 5
i: 6
i: 7
i: 8
i: 9
i: 10
```